# ng-model not updating values immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to make use of [ngAutocomplete](https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete) to have an address parsed out into it's components in text boxes.  The user types their address into a textbox, and upon completion, the address is looked up by ngAutocomplete, returning an array with all of the corresponding components of the address.  I store these in `$scope` variables, and bind them to their corresponding textboxes using `ng-model`.

It seems to be working fine, however, even though I can see that my `$scope` variables are getting updated, the textboxes I have them bound to are not being updated immediately.  In fact, once they don't change until I click inside of the text boxes several times.

Here's the code that I think is relevant, please let me know if more is needed:

HTML:

```
Number: <input type="text" ng-model="address.number"/><br>
Street Address: <input type="text" ng-model="address.street" /><br>
City: <input type="text" ng-model="address.city" /><br>
State: <input type="text" ng-model="address.state" /><br>
Zip: <input type="text" ng-model="address.zip" /><br>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.update = function(details)
{
    $scope.info = details.address_components;
    $scope.members = details.address_components.length;

    $scope.address = {};

    $scope.address.number = $scope.info[0].long_name;
    $scope.address.street = $scope.info[1].long_name;
    $scope.address.city = $scope.info[2].long_name;
    $scope.address.state = $scope.info[4].short_name;
    $scope.address.zip = $scope.info[7].long_name;
}
```

Again, I can clearly see through debugging tools that `number`, `street`, etc. are being updated immediately, it's just not being reflected in the textboxes on the page.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it taking time because of AJAX? I don't know why else it wouldn't be instant.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using any AJAX, and I can wait as long as I want, but it won't show up until I click.

Comment: What triggers the $scope.update(details) ?

Comment: @Nealon looks like you need to run digest cycle..but how it does possible..are you doing ajax using jquery?

Comment: @tiblu I just have {{update(details}} placed in the html body.

Comment: @pankajparkar I'm fairly certain no ajax is being used, unless ngAutocomplete does that underneath somehow.